# GitHub Search API Authentication

Tags: api, authentication, github

I'm trying use the GitHub API to search for Repositories through my app, but every time I send a request from my app I get authentication error:

```
Request forbidden by administrative rules. Please make sure your request has a User-Agent header (http://developer.github.com/v3/#user-agent-required). Check https://developer.github.com for other possible causes.
```

The send request that I send is this:

```
https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=atom
```

I know that I have to provide a username in order to authenticate , but how do I do that withing the request? I don't seem to be finding it in the documentation.

Comment: How are you making the API requests? I tried on the browser and it works fine with the URL you given

Comment: Yes it works with the direct URL, but when I add the exact same on my App, I get authentication error.

Comment: Which app ? How does it make requests ? Is it a python app or android app or iOS ? Show us the code which makes the requests to Github API

Comment: I'm using it in a C++ app for search, I've connected to many APIs ( DuckDuckGO API, Last.fm API, NYTimes API ) but I'm stuck with the request for GitHub. I have to somehow add the client_id etc in the request given above but nothing seems to work.